# I would like to have VB code in excel. If cell "A1:A200 is blank then concananet cells B1:C1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to have VB code in excel. If cell "A1:A200 is blank then concananet cells B1:C1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI0DC.jpg)

Comment: This probably does not even require using VB, the built-in Excel functions might be enough.

Comment: If cell "A1:A200 is blank then concananet cells B1:C1 ? So we could go out on a limb and assume, if column A is blank then concatenate columns B and C from rows 1 to 200? You can simply put =IF(ISBLANK(A1),CONCATENATE(B1,C1),"")

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub FillColumnA()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 200
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value & Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you even write VBA for that? It can be done with a worksheet formula, which will be so much more efficient than VBA, what with all the calls to read and write the cells.

Comment: @teylyn I think it depends, if you want to check value in A column and then overwrite it based on this, then you need store initial value in memory, which can be achieved only in VBA. So, I agree about your general remarks, but in this case, I must disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Shift your data down 1 row and add headers. Set your data up as a table by selecting a populated cell in the range and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then in column D2 put

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),CONCATENATE(B2,C2),"")
```

The table will autofill the rest of the columns with the formula.

If you simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> without shifting your data and then don't select my table has headers, the data will be shifted for you.

[image: Data in table]

Answer (score 2):

no loops

```
Sub FillColumnA()
    With Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
       .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC2,RC3)"
       .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```